# Slope of $sin^{-1}x$ by LHD and visually are coming different

Tags: calculus, continuity

When we check the differentiabilty of $sin^{-1}x$  we take out left hand derivative at $1$ and right hand derivative at$-1$ . When we check the left hand derivative at $1$ it comes out to be tending to negative infinity.

But from the graph I see that the the slope at point $1$ just before reaching point is positive. Though the LHD which denotes the slope, came out to be negative. Why this is so?

Comment: $sin^{-1}x$ is not differentiable at $-1$ and $1$

Comment: How can you obtain a negative slope when the derivative is always positive (and diverges at $1$ and $-1$ as pointed out) ?

Comment: @Ercanayan I am telling that though LHD is coming out to be negative infinity but slope from the graph of sin inverse x is tending from positive value to infinty

Comment: Are you trying to find the one-sided limit $\lim_{h\to0^-}\dfrac{\sin^{-1}(1+h)-\sin^{-1}1}{h}$? Both the numerator and the denominator are negative, so the previous comment was questioning how you obtained *negative* infinity.

Comment: @peterwhy ok got it sir